# Gradle plugin-publish plugin is skipping dependency excludes

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have some transitive dependency excludes in my custom-plugin build script. Like so:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
}

dependencies {
    'org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:2.13',
}
```

When publishing to `plugins.gradle.org` using [com.gradle.plugin-publish](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.plugin-publish) version `0.9.1`, the excludes are not propagated to the generated POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a workaround? Can I somehow use plugin-publish's `withDependencies` extension?

`Maven-publish` plugin has (or at least, used to have)  a similar issue. See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-does-not-add-excludes-to-generated-pom/7297)

**Update:** [This issue is unresolved, and is now logged as a gradle defect.](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3274)

Comment: Have you seen this issue along with the discussion: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2945 ?

Comment: Different plugin. You linked to the maven-publish plugin, which I referenced at the bottom of my question, because the issue is similar. But my question is about the plugin-publish plugin.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You are excluding on the configuration level. Maybe you should try it at the dependency level: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:exclude(java.util.Map) https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the module at the dependency that it is a transitive dependency of:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:2.13') {
        exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
    }
}
```

And this is what you will get in the resulting POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Johan , I assume you've actually tried this and it works? What I posted is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), What I really have is a whole list of jmeter related dependencies, with different excludes based on jmeter version. It is a lot simpler and cleaner to do excludes at the config level. However if this is the only way to do this, I guess I'll accept your answer. I should get a defect/enhancement listed on gradle JIRA. Will test this tonight.

Comment: Yes, this works. I could not test this this afternoon, so I did not post it as an answer then. I just tried to do it on the configuration level and this works too:

configurations {
        compile {
            exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
        }
    }

Check your syntax. It is not correct in your question, so maybe it is incorrect in your scripts too.

Comment: How did you test this BTW? Did you publish a plugin to https://plugins.gradle.org ?

Comment: Just tried what you said about config level exclusions, did not work for me. What gradle version did you use? Perhaps we're talking about different plugins? I'm using [this plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.plugin-publish) and its `publishPlugins` task. [Here is the pom that was generated](https://gradleware-plugins.s3.amazonaws.com/gradle.plugin.net.foragerr.jmeter/jmeter-gradle-plugin/0.6.2beta2-2.13/2c1bbaf4b6302cd89a309916f60899011743a9ea5fb497557d1561ed10ed0293/jmeter-gradle-plugin-0.6.2beta2-2.13.pom) (with missing exclusions)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I totally ignored the fact that you were specifically asking about plug-in publishing. Anyway, I am using Gradle 2.5, and the old `uploadArchives` task with a Maven deployer. But I suspect (and hope) that the POM generation is shared by publication plug-ins. Here is the Gradle script I tested with. Does this work for you? If so, the plug-in publication plug-in is buggy: https://gist.github.com/jstuyts/693739741d2612b6db5c

Comment: `uploadArchives` from the maven plugin works fine for me. You had me very hopeful for a minute there :) Yes, I believe this is a plugin-publish defect. Was trying to see if I could work around it. For instance, the Maven Publishing plugin used to have the [same defect as well](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2945). But it exposed  the pom object and you could work around the problem by manipulating the pom. See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-does-not-add-excludes-to-generated-pom/7297). plugin-publish doesn't seem to expose its pom.

Comment: Sorry, downvote my answer so other people know I did not provide a solution. It is unfortunate that the made the same mistake twice. You would hope that they have a single library for handling all Maven stuff. Couldn't you generate the artifacts and the POM using the _normal_ way, and then do the upload to the plug-in repository yourself?

Comment: No, in fact the answer as you wrote it is perfectly valid. Just checked, calling out excludes explicitly under each dependency works. A major pain in the rear for me, but works. It's just your first comment in this thread that is in error. If I don't see a better compile level workaround I'll even award you the bounty.

Comment: I know gradle is open source, but I am unable to find a github repo for the plugin-publish plugin. I would be happy to submit a patch/pull request.

Comment: I didn't mean fixing the plug-in. I suggested to look at what the plug-in is doing (probably with some network sniffer), and then replicating those actions in a task you wrote yourself that uses the correct output of the standard Maven publication mechanism. Thanks for the bounty, but I don't feel I deserve it.